# Aggregating multiple fields in an elesticsearch object

Tags: json, elasticsearch

I have documents in the following format

```
{
    "reference": "0001",
    "order_outlet": "Brighton",
    "order_amount": 1000,
    "status": "confirmed",
    "checker_conclusions": {
        "conclusion_1": true,
        "conclusion_2": false,
        "conclusion_3": false
    }
}
```

and I would like to aggregate the number of true and false counts for all of the elements in the checker_conclusion object.
I can do it individually using

```
"aggs": {
    "checker_conclusions": {
        "terms": {
            "field": "checker_conclusions.is_pep"
        }
    }
}
```

What do I need to do it for all the fields? Something equivalant to "field":"checker_conclusions.*"
Thanks in advance

I've tried using wildcards and also using dynamic_templates to map them all as keywords

I don't think I'm explaining my question very well, sorry. To simplify. If I have documents like this

```
{
"order_outlet": "Brighton",
"order_amount": 1000,
"status": "confirmed",
"checker_conclusions": {
    "conclusion_1": true,
    "conclusion_2": false,
    "conclusion_3": false
}
```

}

I would like to achieve something like this as an aggregation

```
{
"test_conclusion": {
    "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
    "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
    "buckets": [
        {
            "key": "conclusion_1",
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "true",
                    "doc_count": 1
                },
                {
                    "key": "false",
                    "doc_count": 3
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "key": "conclusion_2",
            "buckets": [
                {
                    "key": "true",
                    "doc_count": 4
                },
                {
                    "key": "false",
                    "doc_count": 2
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Hopefully that makes sense

Answer (score 0):

Try this query with runtime field

```
GET /subfield_aggregation/_search?filter_path=hits.hits
{
    "runtime_mappings": {
        "boolean_counts": {
            "type": "composite",
            "script": {
                "source": """
                    int countBoolean(Set entries, boolean trueOrFalse) {
                        int counter = 0;
                        for (entry in entries) {
                            boolean value = entry.getValue();
                            if (value == trueOrFalse) {
                                counter++;
                            }
                        }   
                        return counter;
                    }
                    
                    Map subfield = params._source['checker_conclusions'];
                    Set entries = subfield.entrySet();

                    Map booleanCounts = [:];
                    booleanCounts['true'] = countBoolean(entries, true);
                    booleanCounts['false'] = countBoolean(entries, false);
                    emit(booleanCounts);
                """
            },
            "fields": {
                "true": {
                    "type": "long"
                },
                "false": {
                    "type": "long"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "fields": ["boolean_counts.true", "boolean_counts.false"],
    "_source": false
}
```

This is by document query, not aggregation

Response

```
{
    "hits" : {
        "hits" : [
            {
                "_index" : "subfield_aggregation",
                "_type" : "_doc",
                "_id" : "1",
                "_score" : 1.0,
                "fields" : {
                    "boolean_counts.false" : [
                        3
                    ],
                    "boolean_counts.true" : [
                        10
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Maybe you convert checker_conclusions nested fields in tags?